# c++ Linked Lists take two object to make one bag

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to write a method for link lists class in c++. I can make it output the first object but I am having trouble output the second object. It is suppose to be a method that takes in two object and displays it as an entire list.

I assume I need to somehow iterate through both object but I've tried many things and I am not having any breakthrough.

This is my current code block for the method. As of right now it takes in obj1 and obj2 but it will only display obj1.

```
template<class ItemType>
LinkedBag<ItemType> LinkedBag<ItemType>::bagUnion(LinkedBag<ItemType> otherBag)
{
    Node<ItemType>* curPtr = new Node<ItemType>;

   while (curPtr->getNext() != nullptr)
   {
    curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
   }
   curPtr->setNext(headPtr);
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: No, it's an assignment that is past due because that I am having trouble with.

Comment: you never use `otherBag`.

Comment: I understand that I never use it this example. But I have attempted to use otherBag before and it either comes out obj1 only or nothing at all.

Comment: @Touchpad your `curPtr` should point to current head (`this->headptr`) at first, not a meaningless new node.

Comment: Why not create a new linked list and use the add or insert function your linked list class pretty much has to have in order to be useful to add all of the items from first one list and then the other?